# Magento 2 - Admin Icons won't load + backend not functional

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

My backend won't load properly.  How can I get it to do this?

Magento 2.0.7 on local MAMP install. 
Have cleared pub/static and the di/*
Using Grunt to compile my LESS commands by 'Grunt watch'

Previously did, "grunt clean", "grunt exec", "grunt less" and then "grunt watch".  Compiled all of the LESS files

```
Running "less:blank" (less) task
File pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.css created: 278.18 kB → 480.04 kB
File pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-l.css created: 72.4 kB → 125.05 kB
File pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email.css created: 6.87 kB → 12.92 kB
File pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/email-inline.css created: 9.98 kB → 18.52 kB

Running "less:luma" (less) task
File pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css created: 327.89 kB → 563.37 kB
File pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css created: 97.12 kB → 165.89 kB

Running "less:backend" (less) task
File pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles-old.css created: 175.36 kB → 286.23 kB
File pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css created: 333.99 kB → 549.53 kB

Running "less:setup" (less) task
>> Destination setup/pub/styles/setup.css not written because no source files were found.

Running "less:updater" (less) task
>> Destination ../magento2-updater/pub/css/updater.css not written because no source files were found.

Running "less:documentation" (less) task
File lib/web/css/docs/docs.css created: 200.39 kB → 341.99 kB
```

[image]

[image: Console errors]

Comment: deploy static content and check again.

Comment: when I run the ```php bin/magento``` it does not find it from the magento root.  Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: which php version and os system are used ?

Comment: MAMP is set for me on 5.6 PHP version.  The bin/magento file is there (so it's a weird error)  OSX version is El Capitan and MAMP is 4.0.4

Comment: You have to set environment variable for windows.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.

Comment: I did not need environment var because of MAMP, but it was a MAMP issue.  I recently upgraded it.  So, I thought because I was using Grunt I would not have to deploy this.  I did have to because I deleted pub/static*
Thank you!  Can you please post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete pub/static/*

Deploy static content by below command.

```
php bin/mangeot setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then You have to compile with Grunt!

Now you will see without any issue in admin.

Comment: Then I can compile with Grunt!

Comment: see my edited answer, is it right steps for the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

to

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

This worked for me.